# Google App Script Question (Send Messages to Slack using a Google Sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script

This current code will send the notification through Slack whenever someone makes any changes in column 5, but unfortunately, it won't work when the changes are done by copy and paste, it only works by manually typing the value in column 5 in the spreadsheet.

```
function sendSlackMessage(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 5) {
    var source = e.source;
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var firstname = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
    var lastname = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    var suspended = e.value;
    var url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/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";
    var payload = {
      text: firstname + " " + lastname + " Google account is suspended " + " = " + suspended
    }

    var headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }

    var options = {
      headers: headers,
      method: 'POST',
      payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
    }

    UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Please advise, should I revise this line:

```
var suspended = e.value;
```

To become like this?

```
var suspended = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange("E:E").getValue();
```

Please advise, what value should I put in getRange?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I guessed that you installed the function `sendSlackMessage` as the installable OnEdit trigger. In this case, when the cell value is put by the copy and paste, the event object has no property of `value`. This is the reason for your current issue. I think that your guess of `Please advise, should I revise this line: var suspended = e.value;` is correct.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var suspended = e.value;
```

#### To:

```
var suspended = e.range.getDisplayValue();
```

or

```
var suspended = e.range.getValue();
```

#### Note:

- By the way, in your showing script, the event object can be used more. And, the values `firstname, lastname, suspended` can be retrieved by one request. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification? In this modification, when column "E" is edited, the values of columns "A", "B" and "E" of the edited row are used as the values `firstname, lastname, suspended`.

```js
function sendSlackMessage(e) {
  // --- I modified the below script.
  const { range } = e;
  if (range.columnStart == 5) {
    var [firstname, lastname, , , suspended] = range.offset(0, -4, 1, 5).getValues()[0];
  // ---

    var url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/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";
    var payload = {
      text: firstname + " " + lastname + " Google account is suspended " + " = " + suspended
    }

    var headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }

    var options = {
      headers: headers,
      method: 'POST',
      payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
    }

    UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, this works; thank you for sharing.
Slack sends a notification when someone makes any changes in the GSheet.
But I guess this solution won't work when running the GAS that has admin SDK, it is updated the gsheet but the Slack notification is not working.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, sure happy to do this! I already accepted the answer and unfortunately can't vote your answer (Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.)